# How to start with garb-gem in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, garb-gem

I am a ruby on rails newbie and like to get some data from the google analytics api with the [garb gem](https://github.com/Sija/garb).
But I struggle at the very beginning. Does anyone have a little sample app to retrieve some data that I can use as a starting point?

KR, Fabian

Comment: Fawyd where do you exactly struggle? At which point.

Comment: @Nobita The ressource are all mentioned in the answer of shrikant1712 (see below). At http://viget.com/extend/introducing-garb-access-the-google-analytics-data-export-api-with-ruby I have some code, but as a newbie I don't know if I have to setup a Session inside my controller or thing like "should I put code xy inside my module?".

Comment: @Nobita I have also try to rebuild an app with the ressource http://www.tweetegy.com/2010/06/using-google-analytics-api-in-a-ruby-on-rails-project/ but I get some errors. The code of this try is on github: https://github.com/fawyd/garbtest

Comment: You probably want to use the Legato gem now as it supports the GA Version 3 API.

Answer (score 3):

you can refer following links for garb

http://geekospace.com/working-with-garb-a-rails-gem-for-google-analytics/

http://viget.com/extend/introducing-garb-access-the-google-analytics-data-export-api-with-ruby

http://www.tweetegy.com/2010/06/using-google-analytics-api-in-a-ruby-on-rails-project/

Comment: thank you for the links. I already know this ressources, but I struggle at the setup like what goes inside the controller, model etc. --> see comment above